# How to add action column with edit and delete option in p-dataTable (Primeng)

Tags: angular, primeng-datatable

I am using primeng ver 5, want to add edit and delete column to primeng datatable.

code to create datatable is given below

```
component
 this.cols = [
      { field: 'id', header: 'Id' },
      { field: 'fname', header: 'First Name' },
      { field: 'lname', header: 'Last Name' }
    ];
```

view.html

```
<p-dataTable  [loading]="loading" [value]="cars" [globalFilter]="gb" [rows]="5" [multiSortMeta]="multiSortMeta" [paginator]="true" [pageLinks]="3" [rowsPerPageOptions]="[5,10,20]">
        <p-column field="id" header="Id" sortable="true"></p-column>
        <p-column field="fname" header="Fname" sortable="true"></p-column>
        <p-column field="lname" header="Lname" sortable="true"></p-column>
      </p-dataTable>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could add two more columns for edit and delete in cols list and in body section of table while iterating could add click events and pass clicked row data as input to those methods or follow example given here : https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-5.2.7/#/table/crud

Answer (score 0):

use action as another column:

```
<p-column field="" header="Actions">
      <ng-template let-car="rowData" pTemplate="body">   
             <i class="far fa-edit primary waves-effect p5" tooltipPosition="top" 
                pTooltip="Edit"></i>
             <i  class="fas fa-trash-alt waves-effect danger p5" tooltipPosition="top" 
                pTooltip="Delete" ></i>                                    
      </ng-template>
</p-column>
```